# How to rewrite this .Net C# in ColdFusion?

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion

I have no idea how to write a byteArray like this in CF

```
b = new byte[] { 0x5e, 0x31, 0x9b, 0xdb, 60, 0x5b };
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on CF but would it be something like this: <cfset myArray = [0x5e, 0x31, 0x9b, 0xdb, 60,0x5b]>

Comment: @dotNetZombie sadly CF doesn't recognize 0x5e (and the like) as a valid primitive value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary objects in ColdFusion are Byte Arrays.  Here is an example:

```
<cfset bytes = ToBinary(ToBase64("ABCDEF"))>

<cfloop array="#bytes#" index="byte">
<cfoutput>#byte#</cfoutput><br>
</cfloop>
```

This outputs:

```
65
66
67
68
69
70
```

*edit*

I discovered something unpleasant about ColdFusion in answering this... namely, that CF apparently treats all numbers as signed, and so refuses to cast a value over 127 into a byte field.  In order to get a value over 127 (such as, in your example, 0x9b/155), you have to cast it as unsigned.  Unfortunately, this is not that easy to do.  However, I've whipped up a little function which makes it easier:

```
<cffunction name="uint">
    <cfargument name="val">
    <cfargument name="radix" default="16">
    <cfreturn CreateObject('java', 'org.apache.axis.types.UnsignedInt').init(InputBaseN(arguments.val, arguments.radix)).byteValue()>
</cffunction>

<cfset bin = JavaCast("byte[]", 
        [
            uint('5e'), 
            uint('31'), 
            uint('9b'), 
            uint('db'), 
            uint('db'), 
            uint('60', 10), 
            uint('5b')
        ])>
<cfdump var="#ToBase64(bin, 'utf-16')#">
```

Comment: Please see updated version, which actually works with the values you provided.

Comment: Though the latter works, it is much simpler to just binaryDecode the hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to do this using Java if you want a true Byte array as ColdFusion doesn't have byte arrays.

I'd ask what your using it for as there is probably another solution, however, [this post](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/01/byte_arrays_and_1.html) will probably assist you creating a Java Byte array

Comment: Binary objects in coldfusion are byte arrays.

Comment: Did you down vote my answer then propose a solution that uses Java :)

Comment: All coldfusion uses java ultimately. I only downvoted due to this statement: "ColdFusion doesn't have byte arrays".  That is simply untrue.

Comment: Also - my java version is only needed if they absolutely need to start with hex values.  Otherwise, the first portion of my answer (with no reference to java classes/casting) works fine.

Comment: Fair enough, technically however if ColdFusion had byte arrays, you wouldn't need to javacast it :)

Comment: I have used the technique mentioned in the article. But it is worth noting that it was written before javacast("byte[]") existed ;)

Comment: Personally I think mine is better ;) Nothing against Jake's suggestion, but it can be done in one function call, even using hex. I doubt they need to duplicate the C# code exactly, just agree upon one encoding (hex or base64) and get the same results.

Answer (score 2):

They are just expressing most of the values in hexadecimal. Remove the leading `0x`'s, which are not used in CF. Then concatenate everything into a single string and use binaryDecode to convert it to a byte array:

```
<!--- this is equivalent to 0x5e, 0x31, 0x9b, 0xdb, 60, 0x5b --->
<cfset bytes = binaryDecode("5e319bdb3c5b", "hex")>
```

**Edit**: As noted below the C# code switched syntax mid-stream and threw in one unsigned value in the middle of the hexadecimal values:

```
       0x5e - 94 in hex
       0x31 - 49 in hex
       0x9b - 155 in hex 
       0xdb - 219 in hex 
       60   - ** unsigned byte value
       0x5b - 91 in hex
```

However you do not have to do the same in your CF code. In fact it is probably better if you do *not*, because it requires more complex code. By using only hex, you can create the byte array in a single line of code. Plus it is more consistent and readable. Just use [formatBaseN](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e1c.html) to convert any unsigned values like `60` to hex.

```
       5e
       31 
       9b
       db
       3c   <= formatBaseN(60, 16)
       5b
```

Comment: This definitely is a nice and simple means of going from hex to a byte array, but one of OP's digits is decimal.  Slight modification needed for that.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. But knowing the end result is the same, it seemed wrong that the c# code switched syntax in the middle of the game. Personally I think it is better to be consistent and express it all one way or the other ie all hex or all unsigned bytes. (Edit) Thanks, I will make a note of the change.

Comment: Yeah I agree, this is nice. And I think that decimal in the middle might be a mistake.

Comment: Or just laziness ;) C# and java are strongly typed, so they will accept either one - or even a mix of both. With CF being typeless, it does not really support that exact construct. So trying to duplicate it is awkward and leads to some unwieldy code. In CF it is more natural if you stick with one style (hex or change to base64) and decode it. Either way the results will be the same as in C#

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.getBytes()` method on java Strings.

For example:

```
<cfscript>
var test = "abc123";
var testBytes = test.getBytes("UTF-8");
</cfscript>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29

Comment: True, but in this case taking the bytes of the literal string will not result in the same value.

Comment: Do you have an example where it fails?

Comment: Any hex (or base64) string, like `5e319bdb3c5b`. Just using getBytes("utf-8") will not decode them properly. It returns the binary of the individual characters instead of the hex *pairs*. So in this case you end up with 12 bytes when there should be 6.

Comment: Put another way, the input is `hex`, not `UTF-8`. So it needs to be *decoded as hex* to get the correct answer. Using `getBytes("UTF-8")` does not cause an error, but it does not return the correct bytes either.